# Are Web Description Protocols useful for SEO

Tags: seo, meta-tags, rdfa

I feel new to SEO world, but for now everything I have found are like 20+ html meta tags where only 3 or 4 are in common use, the point is that after some digging I am on the crossroad between taking easy way and just stick to title / description / keyword meta tags, or to go further and spend some hours to learn about RDF, POWDER, and other notations that are uncommon in HTML documents.

What is the possible highest benefit for SEO when using web description protocols like RDF?

Comment: Do not over think this. Simple works. But study some more before you get started. Start here: https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo